# I have both WAMP and APACHE installed. Do i just need one or both?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I downloaded APACHE to use as a server on my local machine. I tested it by turning it on 'http.exe' I believe it's called. And storing a 'index.php' file that just says "It works". It showed this file when I went on local host on my browser.

I've downloaded My SQL work bench, and WAMP, and PHPMyAdmin.

My question is, do I need to uninstall Apache since my WAMP local server is on. Because when I type in local host in to my browser it takes me to the WAMP server configuration page, instead of showing "It works".

So does this mean I don't need Apache any more?

Comment: WAMP **includes** Apache.

Comment: Apache is part of WAMP (Windows Apache Mysql PHP)

Comment: WAMP: Windows + Apache + MySQL + PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WAMP` is basically `Apache,php and Mysql` package. Once it is installed you have installed these 3 and ready to go. You don't need separate one. `Phpmyadmin` also installed there.

Once it is installed you can have a tray icon in right bottom of the desktop. Use this menu to manage `Wamp` for eg: Start or stop Apace and Mysql, configure Apache,PHP and Mysql etc. Once you started the apache and mysql. Just type `http://localhost` in web browser to check the installation is ok or not. Remember `C:/wamp/www` is the webroot where your php files should go.

Comment: Sorry I was busy, all answers were helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wamp includes Apache, so you don't need a separate installation.

Answer (score 2):

**WAMP** stands for "**W**indows **A**pache **M**ySQL **P**HP"

So having WAMP means you have Apache, PHP, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin etc.

To run PHP code you need Apache server. And WAMP **is** an apache server environment. Same as LAMP (Linux version) or XAMPP (my favourite, stands for "**Cross**-platform **A**pache **M**ySQL **P**HP **P**erl")

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I'm new to the world of programming in the sense of servers. I will delete my APACHE folder. Thanks!

Comment: WAMP works fine, done a 'test.php' file in the 'www' folder and it showed up on the browser.