# How to run Apache server and WAMP on same machine without using a VM?

Tags: apache, windows-10, wamp, wampserver, apache2.4

### MY ISSUE

I manually installed **Apache 2.4 web server** in 2014 on my local backup laptop, which I haven't done development on since 2016.

Forgetting Apache was already installed on my backup laptop, I installed **WAMPServer** a few days ago. But, when I type localhost in Chrome, the standalone Apache server is launched instead of the one included with WAMPServer.

I'm a newbie as far as server installation and configuration, but I suspect the answer may have something to do with ports, which I don't completely understand.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

I found [this video on How to use XAMPP and WAMP server on same pc in Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt0XvtYfoGE) and followed these steps, derived from my interpretation of the video:

**NOTE:** My earlier suspectation seems to be correct => ***The key appears to be calling one of the servers on a different port***.

1. Decide which server will be the one you call with vanilla "localhost". I chose the manually installed Apache, so WAMP will be my secondary that will need port specified.
2. In `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\conf\` open **httpd.conf** and edit as follows:

```
    Listen 0.0.0.0:90
    Listen [::0]:90
```

3. In `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21` open **my.ini** and edit as follows:

```
    [client]
    ;password = your_password
    port = 3390

    [wampmysqld]
    ;skip-grant-tables
    port = 3390
```

4. Save changes in both files.
5. Right-click on the "W" in the lower right corner of the taskbar and chose "refresh".
6. Open browser and navigate to *localhost:90*

So that all works.

#### The weird thing

But, when I go to vanilla 'localhost' it gives me an error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

And, even stranger, when I do view source, it shows me the HTML for my index.html file, even though it says the server can't connect.

For good measure I tried 'localhost:80' but that gives me the same error.

### MY QUESTION

So, my question is this:

- How can I run standalone, manually-installed Apache 2.4 server and WAMPServer side-by-side on the same Windows 10 64-bit machine (without using a virtual machine or dual-boot setup)?
- Is this just a matter of port configuration, as I suspected?

### Addendum

This is not a duplicate of [#27858784](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858784/i-have-both-wamp-and-apache-installed-do-i-just-need-one-or-both) because that OP is asking whether he needs one or both and none of the respondents answer my significantly different question of "**how can I have both**".

Comment: Not sure if this was a cache issue or something else, but all of a sudden - today it is working. Should I delete the post?

Comment: And now it is NOT working again. But this time, "localhost" works, but "localhost:3330" errors out with: `This page isn’t working
localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` ... maybe I should post that as a separate issue?